# How to send data from one app to another without UI in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm sending some data from one app to another app and retrieving also when it's required what works fine. But I'm having an issue that second app always comes in foreground while retrieving the data due to that onResume function always gets called. I don't want the receiver app's activity to be in the foreground state.

Sender App's activity:

```
  protected fun writeSharedLoginStatus(loginStatus: Boolean) {
    Log.d(mTag, "writeSharedLoginStatus: $loginStatus")
    try {
        loginStatusLauncher.launch(
            Intent(UtilConstants.ACTION_WRITE_LOGIN_STATUS).putExtra(
                UtilConstants.ACTION_EXTRA_LOGIN_STATUS,
                loginStatus
            )
        )
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Log.e(mTag, "Launch ACTION_WRITE_LOGIN_STATUS failed with exception: ${e.message}")
    }
}


  private val loginStatusLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        Log.d(mTag, "loginStatusLauncher onResult ${result.resultCode}")
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val loginStatus =
                result.data?.getBooleanExtra(UtilConstants.ACTION_EXTRA_LOGIN_STATUS, false)
                    ?: false
            loginUtility.updateLoginStatus(loginStatus)
        }
    }
```

Receiver App's Activity:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    when (val action = intent.action) {
        UtilConstants.ACTION_READ_LOGIN_STATUS -> handleReadLoginStatus()
        UtilConstants.ACTION_WRITE_LOGIN_STATUS -> handleWriteLoginStatus()
        else -> {
            Log.e(mTag, "Unsupported action: $action")
            finish()
        }
    }
}

  private fun handleReadLoginStatus() {
    if (!this::sharedPref.isInitialized) {
        sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    val loginStatus = sharedPref.getBoolean(UtilConstants.ACTION_EXTRA_LOGIN_STATUS, false)
    Log.i(mTag, "handleReadLoginStatus: $loginStatus")

    setResult(
        Activity.RESULT_OK,
        Intent().putExtra(UtilConstants.ACTION_EXTRA_LOGIN_STATUS, loginStatus)
    )

    finish()
}

private fun handleWriteLoginStatus() {
    if (!this::sharedPref.isInitialized) {
        sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    val loginStatus = intent.getBooleanExtra(UtilConstants.ACTION_EXTRA_LOGIN_STATUS, false)
    Log.i(mTag, "handleWriteLoginStatus: $loginStatus")
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putBoolean(UtilConstants.ACTION_EXTRA_LOGIN_STATUS, loginStatus)
        apply()
    }

    setResult(
        Activity.RESULT_OK,
        Intent().putExtra(UtilConstants.ACTION_EXTRA_LOGIN_STATUS, loginStatus)
    )

    finish()
}
```

I would appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, but I think you shouldn't use Activity (which is pretty much an UI screen), but a Service.